# Using JQUERY and PHP to update mysql when link is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have at the moment two tabs that a user can click between, from their update profile page and upload media page that they can upload like pics and such. I want to make it easier for the user so when they click update profile, it then updates a mysql boolean column called "user_upanel" to 1 and clicking upload media will update to 0 so when the page is refreshed or if they come back the page they left is still the top most page. How can I accomplish this using jquery or should I use ajax instead? I am assuming I should add a POST method using a form from what I have googled but haven't yet found a solution to my problem so far.

So far I can get mysql to update to a 1 if I remove the if else statement and have only the first php statement but having it the way it is now won't update the 0 when I switch between tabs. I figure my code is way off but I tried lol.

```
<ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab"><a href="#update">Update Profile</a></li>
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#upload">Upload Media</a></li>
</ul>


$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.tab-group:first-child').hasClass('active')){
        <?php
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "accounts");
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_upanel = 1 WHERE user_username = '$user_username'";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        ?>
    }else{
        <?php
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "accounts");
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_upanel = 0 WHERE user_username = '$user_username'";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        ?>
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using ajax like in the below example:

Html:

```
   <ul class="tab-group">
      <li class="tab" data-tab="1"><a href="#update">Update Profile</a></li>
      <li class="tab" data-tab="2"><a href="#upload">Upload Media</a></li>
    </ul>
```

php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["user_upanel"])){
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "accounts");
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_upanel = '".$_POST['user_upanel']."' WHERE user_username = '".$_POST['user_username']."'";
  mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
?>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').click(function(){
      var user_upanel=$(this).data('tab');
      $.ajax({
        url:'your php file path',
        type:'post',
        data:{
          user_upanel:user_upanel,
          user_username:'foo'
        }
      })
    })
  }
</script>
```